# Timeout when passing large table-valued parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, timeout, table-valued-parameters

I am calling a SQL Server stored procedure using ADO.NET, and I have to pass a very large Table-Valued parameter. I get this timeout exception very often:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.
The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. --->
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

I am calling `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`, which according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not affected by the CommandTimeout.

The question is: what timeout value should I increase to be able to pass that large TVP to the stored procedure without getting a timeout?

Comment: "I have to pass a very large Table-Valued parameter" - do you have to construct this table in C# code, or could you materialise it in the proc?

Comment: I have to construct it in C#, all of it is new input to the database (sort of like a bulk operation).

Answer (score 1):

A solution that helped me recently with this situation was increasing the Connection Timeout (not to be mistaken with Command Timeout).  This makes me think that sometimes when there is a lot of data being passed to a stored procedure via a table value parameter that it can sometimes take longer to initialize the connection (this occurred during peak usage but not when the system was under low load).  A simple way to increase the Connection Timeout is via the query string.

Example of setting timeout to 120 seconds instead of the default 15:

```
"Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=120;"
```